# In React, how to constrain a prop to be passed only once per value

Tags: reactjs

```
type DndBoxProps = React.PropsWithChildren<{
  accepts?: any[];
  // "all" 
  // "left" | "right" | "top" | "bottom"
  edge?: string[];
}>
```

If I pass 'all', then cannot pass 'top', 'right', 'left', 'bottom'.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom type using discriminating union

```
type EdgeType = 'all' | 'left' | 'right' | 'top' | 'bottom';

type Edge =
    | { edges: ['all'] }
    | { edges: Exclude<EdgeType, 'all'>[] }

type DndBoxProps = React.PropsWithChildren<{
    accepts?: any[];
    edgeConfig?: Edge;
}>;

export function DndBox(props: DndBoxProps) {
    return (
        <>
            {props.edgeConfig?.edges.map((edge) => {
                return <h3>{edge}</h3>
            })}
        </>
    )
}
```

This way `<DndBox edgeConfig={{edges: ['all', 'left']}} />` - will raise error

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply!
I don't think this solution of yours is good enough.

```
edges={{edges:['bottom','bottom']} will silence
```

This has the same check as your answer

```
type E =  "left" | "right" | "top" |  "bottom"

type DndBoxProps = React.PropsWithChildren<{
  accepts?: any[];

  edge?: ["all"] | E[] ;
}>;
```

I have now changed it to

```
type DndBoxProps = React.PropsWithChildren<{
  accepts?: any[];
  top?: boolean;
  right?: boolean;
  bottom?: boolean;
  left?: boolean;
  
}>;
```